# Is there a better way to clone an N-ary tree iteratively?

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

I'm looking for a better, or more optimized, method for copying (or in the actual problem, transforming) an n-ary tree *without* using recursion. Some details regarding the general situation that I'm trying to solve are as follows

- Tree is n-ary (i.e., up to n nodes per level)
- Children have link to parent and parent has list of all children
- In any given level of the tree, any node may be  a leaf or a branch

I've come up with the following solution. The general approach is to use two (three) stacks. The first keeps track of the items from the original tree that need to be processed, and the second keeps track of the newly created copies so that we can appropriately assign linkage between nodes (this could be divided into two stacks instead of Tuples, hence three). This works but it has a number of undesirable aspects, the first being that it just feels incredibly awkward. I'm thinking that there has to be a better way to do this and I am missing something (or multiple things that are) obvious.

Has anyone encountered anything more direct / more efficient approach?

```
public TreeNode ConvertTree(TreeNode root)
{
    Stack<TreeNode> processingStack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    Stack<Tuple<Int32, TreeNode>> resultStack = new Stack<Tuple<Int32, TreeNode>>();
    TreeNode result = null;

    processingStack.Push(root);
    while (processingStack.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentProcessingNode = processingStack.Pop();
        var parentNode = resultStack.Count > 0 ? resultStack.Pop() : null;

        // Copies all leaf nodes and assigns parent, if applicable.
        var newResultNode = CopyNodeData(currentProcessingNode, parentNode != null ? parentNode.Item2 : null);

        // Push sub-branch nodes onto the processing stack, and keep track of how many for
        // each level.
        var subContainerCount = 0;
        foreach (var subContainer in currentProcessingNode.Children.Where(c => !c.IsLeaf))
        {
            processingStack.Push(subContainer);
            subContainerCount++;
        }

        // If we have have not processed all children in this parent, push it back on and
        // decrement the counter to keep track of it.
        if (parentNode != null && parentNode.Item1 > 1)
        {
            resultStack.Push(new Tuple<Int32, TreeNode>(parentNode.Item1 - 1, parentNode.Item2));
        }

        // If this node has sub-branches, push the newly copied node onto the result/tracking
        // stack
        if(subContainerCount > 0)
            resultStack.Push(new Tuple<Int32, TreeNode>(subContainerCount, newResultNode));

        // The very first time a new node is created, track it to return as the result
        if (newResultNode.IsRoot)
            result = newResultNode;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Please note that I am *NOT* looking for a recursive solution. Yes I realize that they are available, simple, and appropriate in many situations. This question is more about HOW this type of operation can be done efficiently in an iterative manner, not just how to pull it off period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a crack at it. This assumes a link to the parent and that you can retrieve the number of children on a node and access a child by index.

```
static TreeNode Clone(TreeNode root)
{
    var currentOriginal = root;
    var currentCloned = Copy(root, null);
    var clonedRoot = currentCloned;
    while (currentOriginal != null)
    {
        if (currentCloned.Children.Count == currentOriginal.Children.Count)
        {
            currentOriginal = currentOriginal.Parent;
            currentCloned = currentCloned.Parent;
        }
        else
        {
            var targetChild = currentOriginal.Children[currentCloned.Children.Count];
            currentOriginal = targetChild;
            currentCloned = Copy(currentOriginal, currentCloned);
        }
    }
    return clonedRoot;
}


static TreeNode Copy(TreeNode source, TreeNode parent) { ... }
```

We initialize:

- A working variable, for the original tree
- A working variable, for the cloned tree
- The root of the cloned tree (so the code is cleaner, the alternative would be to return `currentCloned` and change the line in the first `if` branch to `currentCloned = currentCloned.Parent ?? currentCloned`)

We loop until we have nothing more to process. There are two options:

- The clone's number of children are the same as the source's number of children. This means there is either a leaf node or all children have been processed. Move up to the parent.
- The clone has less children than the original, this means one or more children should be processed, process the next child using the indexer trick above.

Because we can link to the parent using the tree itself, no stacks are needed to aid navigation.

Comment: Nice! Much more elegant than using multiple stacks for navigation and tracking. This is exactly the sort of solution I felt that I was overlooking.